# How can I modify HTTP headers in ASP.NET (Web Forms) that are defined in web.config

Tags: asp.net, http-headers, web-config, content-security-policy, managed

I have some custom HTTP response headers defined in an `ASP.NET` (Web Forms) website's web.config.

I'm trying to write a `managed HTTP module` that can modify these `web.config` defined headers before they're sent back to the client.  Unfortunately, whatever event I use (PreSendRequestHeaders, EndRequest) , the headers defined in `web.config` do not exist in the `Response.Headers` collection.

I'm aware that `PreSendRequestHeaders` is not recommended so I also tried using `Response.AddOnSendingHeaders` but this doesn't give me access to the headers either.

Specifically what I'm trying to do is address inline script for our `Content Security Policy (CSP)`.  I'd like to automatically add a nonce attribute to all inline script blocks (I have a working POC for this) and then modify the `HTTP CSP header` (defined in web.config) to add the 'nonce-' items into the `script-src` section.

I don't want to add the `CSP header` in code because it changes often enough that recompile and publish of the website would be a pain.

Do I need to resort to a native `IIS module` to achieve this or is there some way to do it using managed code (preferred)?