# Is it possible to edit the custom Content-Security-Policy header set by IIS / web.config?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, content-security-policy

I am wondering if it's possible to modify the `Content-Security-Policy` header that is set under `<customHeaders>` within *web.config*.

I would like to inject a nonce value if possible. I am currently doing this but I need to remove the header from *web.config* entirely and add it via `Application_BeginRequest()`

I have poked around *global.asax* to grab the header. It doesn't seem exist at this point in the pipe line. I can only assume it is injected later on?

```xml
<customHeaders>
     <add name="Content-Security-Policy" value="myCsp nonce-{injectMe}" />
</customHeaders>
```

```cs
// would like to do something akin to this:
protected void Application_BeginRequest()
{
    var nonce = 'myNonce';
    Response.Headers["Content-Security.Policy"] =
        Response.Headers["Content-Security.Policy"].Replace("{injectMe}", nonce);
}
```

The goal being to keep the CSP within *web.config* and not having to rebuild when changing it.

Is this possible at all?

Comment: as a workaround, I've set the CSP as an app setting, and pull that into global.asax. This why it can still be edited on the fly and kept in the config. That said, still interested if anyone knows if the header can be reached as asked.

Comment: i also found the only workable solution to be to move the CSP header from customHeaders into appSettings. IIS applies the custom headers *after* application logic has processed the request, and i know of no way to change it on the fly. you should write up your solution as the answer to this question; its valuable.

Comment: also, this is a possible duplicate of the unanswered question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49128302/how-can-i-modify-http-headers-in-asp-net-web-forms-that-are-defined-in-web-con ; suggest you give an answer there

Answer (score 2):

I believe what you're looking for is Context.Response.Headers["Content-Security.Policy"].Replace("{injectMe}", nonce);

This should grab the current Context of the request being initiated, if I'm correct.